# Docker command with env var prepended (local env var)

Tags: python, shell, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I am using Docker Compose to spin up some containers, but I don't get the `command` working. I would like to start my Flask server, but also set an env var for it. Here's what I've done:

```
web:
  command: INSTASONG_ENV=production python manage.py runserver
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Cannot start container 2a413b1270b9faa5e0ffb8a70603ae25c48ff742e0d8476bed8153febcee185a: [8] System error: exec: "INSTASONG_ENV=production": executable file not found in $PATH
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting environment variable might be set differently, as illustrated in [`tests/fixtures/extends/common.yml`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/49c2080bcda293c67652429999f6353e4285f8af/tests/fixtures/extends/common.yml)

```
web:
  image: busybox
  command: /bin/true
  environment:
    - FOO=1
    - BAR=1
```

In your case:

```
web:
  command: python manage.py runserver
  environment:
    - INSTASONG_ENV=production
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, missed the obvious and went searching for the twisted. Thank you!